# Graph Optimization Problems

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, discrete-optimization, operations-research, extremal-graph-theory

I'm having a bit of trouble finding any references in the literature about optimizing functions defined on the set of graphs, i.e. in particular where the number of vertices is not fixed. For example, consider generalizations of finding a graph of minimum size that maximizes the max flow between two fixed and distinguished vertices subject to various constraints on the edge capacities and vertex degrees.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is called "extremal graph theory", but that's a very broad field and you're asking a very specific problem.

Comment: Thanks Misha, I did not think to look at extremal graph theory. On the other hand, I am looking more towards rigorous approaches for solving engineering problems (e.g. designing communications networks or designing structures, etc.). I am not even sure what stackexchange (maybe cs?) might be better suited for this question!

Answer (score 0):

This is called max flow-min cut problem in graphs that states that max flow from a given source to a sink is equal to minimum cut that will separate the source from the sink. Basically these are kind of dual problem as you'll find in an LP and is proven by Ford-Fulkerson theorem.
References:
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)
[Princeton](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring06/cos226/lectures/maxflow.pdf)

Comment: I think you're confusing "find the max flow" and "find the graph that maximizes the max flow".